# no SysWOW64 support has been found. The Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) will disable the application pool

Tags: iis, syswow64

In IIS, I have configured websites and configured in Application for Enable 32 bit application to run. It was working fine for years and today I faced frequent shutdown of Application Pool. Then I captured the following log details from Event log under System log.

"The application pool 'xxxxxx' has enabled 32-bit worker processes, but no SysWOW64 support has been found. The Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) will disable the application pool.  To resolve this issue, either disable running as 32-bit worker processes or install the SysWOW64 support.  The data field contains the error number."

I have tried to resolve the using Google, but no proper solution to enable of SysWOW64 support in IIS.

Anybody do let me know the configuration procedure to resolve my problem.

Comment: What Windows version? WOW64 is now optional and must be manually enabled on Windows Server.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Windows Server 2008 R2